# How can I tab inside a text box?

Tags: macos, keyboard, html

I'm using OS X and when I am typing in a text box and press the tab key, it will jump to the next HTML element on the page. I've tried using the modifier keys to prevent this from happening but that doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way I can get my keyboard to type "tabs" in a text box without having to copy and paste them from another editing tool?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Firefox, check this extension: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tabinta/

Comment: Thanks! What about for Chrome?

Comment: This would do: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dgkbnngeehclnibbdblaimapibmmcdal

Comment: Thanks @karatedog that is a pretty sweet extension for Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

It's usually `Ctrl-Opt-Tab` if `Tab` is used to move keyboard focus to a different element, but seems to require a well-behaved OS X application. It works in Safari, iTunes, Things, Automator, etc.

Comment: Great! Now I've got this working with 3 of 3 browser I have installed.